# .NET MS Interop Word not saving document in UTF8 web page

Tags: .net, office-interop

Note: A sample document I used for test can be foud in: http://ftp.3gpp.org//Specs/archive/38_series/38.413/38413-100.zip

## Problem

I am trying to convert an MS Word 97-2003 document (.doc) into a UTF-8 web page with the following code:

```cs
var wordApp = new Word.Application();
var doc = wordApp.Documents.Open("input.doc");
Console.WriteLine(doc.TextEncoding); // msoEncodingWestern
doc.SaveEncoding = MsoEncoding.msoEncodingUTF8;
doc.WebOptions.Encoding = MsoEncoding.msoEncodingUTF8;
doc.SaveAs2("output.htm", WdSaveFormat.wdFormatFilteredHTML, Encoding: MsoEncoding.msoEncodingUTF8);
doc.Close();
wordApp.Quit();
```

The problem is the document contains a certain character which is rendered incorrectly in a web page:

**In document**

[image]

**In web page**

[image]

## (Information) Manual Way

For information, if I do the above in a manual way as below, the arrow character is rendered correctly in web page.

[image]

Comment: Can you paste the characters here in your question?

Comment: @HackSlash  This is what I copy-and-pasted from doc to SO (Yes... a square, literally...). In unicode, it says `U+F0AE` (checked in VSCode with *Unicode code point of current character* extension) I am not sure whether even the unicode value is correct or not... Anyway I will try the solution you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with the following:

```
var from = ((char)0xF0AE).ToString();
var to = ((char)0x2192).ToString();
doc.Content.Find.Execute(from, ReplaceWith: to, Replace: WdReplace.wdReplaceAll);
```

It's not a generalized solution, i.e. this method only handles a right arrow case and another method needs to be defined if a left arrow is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have cited the encoding in too many different ways. You should only need to set it once.

Try this:

```
var wordApp = new Word.Application();
var doc = wordApp.Documents.Open("input.doc");
doc.Fields.Update(); // ** this is the new line of code.
Console.WriteLine(doc.TextEncoding); // msoEncodingWestern
doc.WebOptions.Encoding = MsoEncoding.msoEncodingUTF8;
doc.SaveAs2("output.htm", WdSaveFormat.wdFormatFilteredHTML);
doc.Close();
wordApp.Quit();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't solve the problem. The output is the same. :(